# Youngnuo flash as a compatible slave flash

Tags: canon, off-camera-flash, compatibility, yongnuo

I have a 600EX-RT Canon flash, and am looking for a cheap Yongnuo flash to be used as a slave to the Canon. Do you know any Yongnuo than can **reliably** be used as a slave to my 600EXRT ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what method of slaving we're talking about and your definition of reliable.

If you mean as a dumb optical slave, where the main flash burst from the 600EX-RT can trigger the flash, then all of the YN flashes have "dumb" slave modes on them.

If you mean as a wireless eTTL near-infrared optical slave, then any of the Yongnuo flashes with **EX** in the name can be used as a slave with the 600EX-RT as an *optical* master.

If you mean as an RF slave in the Canon RT system, then the [YN600EX-RT](http://flashhavoc.com/yongnuo-yn600ex-rt-now-available/) is a cheap clone of the Canon 600EX-RT, and the Yongnuo [YNE3-RX](http://flashhavoc.com/?s=YNE3-RX) radio receiver can be added to Canon and Yongnuo (and one assumes anybody else's) eTTL and menu-commandable models (e.g., a YN-568EXII or YN-500EX) for triggering and control from an RT master unit.

A note: with flashes you can have any of the following two things: lots of features, a low price, or rock solid reliability.  You want cheap and rock solid reliable, then an RT feature set via a cheap Chinese clone may not be the right path. There are reports on early 600EX-RT units being great and reliable. There are also reports of them having dead scanlines on the LCD screens, battery drain issues, and making weird noises. If you have to have something rock-solid reliable, then a Canon 600EX-RT is probably your best bet.  If you just need hobbyist usage sufficient, then Yongnuo's a no-brainer.

See also:

- [What flash slaves can be used with a Canon Speedlite 600EX-RT?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/29052/what-flash-slaves-can-be-used-with-a-canon-speedlite-600ex-rt)
- [What does an expensive flash unit buy over a cheap one?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/33842/what-does-an-expensive-flash-unit-buy-over-a-cheap-one)

Answer (score 2):

The [Yongnuo YN600EX-RT](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OUU7W8O) is pretty much a clone of the [Canon 600EX-RT](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007FH1KX2) and can be used as either master or slave in combination with it.

Comment: Thanks, but its price range is almost $500.00, I was hoping for a cheap Yongnuo one...

Comment: It's $126 at the **first** link in the answer. That's barely 1/4 of $500!